# What is Large about the LHC?

Tags: soft-question, terminology, large-hadron-collider

Does the Large in Large Hadron Collider describe the collider or the hadrons?
I looked into it a bit and am posting this to share my answer with the community.  I'm also required to write so much in the question box because the autochecks don't allow me to submit a short question.

Comment: See also [Relativistic Heavy Ion Collider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Heavy_Ion_Collider).

Comment: *What is Large about the LHC?* - everything!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about names rather than physics.

Comment: I admit I'm new to the physics SE, but this started with the idea that there might be a set of hadrons which are considered large, and other which are not (or considered small).  I wanted a way to share the internet research I did to find the answer to my own question and correct the misconception the the LHC was built for "large hadrons".

Comment: I tried to change the question to explicitly make the mistake (e.g. What are the largest hadrons that can be collided in the Large Hadron Collider), but then I thought that this would be bad for the community because people who just read the title of the question would walk away thinking that hadrons really are categorized by size.

Comment: @JohnRennie including (or especially) the running costs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked up the French name and it is "Grand collisionneur de hadrons", so I guess the collider is large, not the hadrons. 
Also, it replaced the LEP (Large electron-positron), so I guess anyhting in that 27km tunnel qualifies as Large.

BTW, The term hadron was introduced by Lev B. Okun (according to wikipedia) from the Greek ἁδρός signifies "large", "massive". So the LHC is the Large Large-thing Collider.  However, some playing with Google Translate does not confirm that Greek meaning.